# How to return a string by concatenating characters in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-concatenation

I have written the following code in Python 2.7

```
class BinaryCode:
    def decode(self, message):
        result = str(0)
        result += str(message[0])
        for i in range(1, len(message)-1):
            result += str(int(message[i])-int(result[i])-int(result[i-1]))
        return result
```

When I initialise message as 123210122, I want the result to be 011100011 but instead it's {"0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1"}. How to do this?

This is a topcoder SRM 144 Div 2 problem and this was the result.

[image]

Now, when I run this code in IDLE it gives me a string but then why its not working in topcoder?

Comment: ''.join(result) just before return result

Comment: I just ran that, it returns `011100011` (so either this is not the code you run, or this is not the input you obtain)

Comment: @sunny: why would that work? do you not think `result` is already supposed to be a string?

Comment: ok i figured it out. he wants the result to be the number in binary, not a string. not very obvious but after running his code that's the only interpretation i can have.

Comment: @sunny Same thing, does'nt work

Comment: @bbill I want to return a string not a binary number

Comment: If I make sure `message` is a string, then this works fine...

Comment: exactly haha. thought of the more convoluted case instead of the simpler mistake.

Comment: In fact, if I run `print type(decode("123210122"))`, I get `<type 'str'>`...

Comment: Even if I run `print type(decode(['1','2','3','2','1','0','1','2','2']))`, I get `<type 'str'>`. How are you not getting a string back?

Answer (score 0):

Just change last line of function to `return ''.join(result)`.